# How can edit object list dynamic in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic

Example in C#:

```
List<dynamic> ListaPersonas = new List<dynamic>() {
    new { valor= 1,Nombre="maria"},
    new { valor= 2,Nombre="jose"},
    new { valor =3,Nombre="juan"}
};          

foreach (var item in ListaPersonas)
    if (item.Nombre == "jose")
        item.valor = 7;
```

**Error**

> Can not assign property or indexer `'<> f__AnonymousType0 <int, string> .value'` because it is read-only

I have a list with data and I have to go through it and apply validations, which causes some values to be modified. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be dynamic?  This would be really easy to solve with a concrete class

Comment: You can't assign to a property of an anonymous type. If you need to assign new values to the properties of those items, they can't be anonymous.

Comment: No, what he should do is build a proper class.

Comment: Using ExpandoObject will give you possibility check if a property exists in an object and also assign sought value.

Comment: It's just an example, because I really have to create 41 classes in an application, But they are simple class with only public properties, no methods or events. I can not create many class files. The dynamics of objects that allows the transport of data, which do very well. But they can only be read ?. How can I change its values ​​at runtime using dynamic objects?

Comment: Why cant you create 41 POCO classes?  If you have 41 different types of objects that make up an application I see no reason why you can't define them, then use them?

Comment: I am learning to work with dynamic objects is just to know another alternative

Comment: So the requirement is you **have** to use `dynamic`?  You mention that its an alternative, but is it really?  You cannot assign to properties of anonymous types, so you would have to create leagues of ExpandoObjects with whatever properties, then have a bunch of code overhead just to check if a property exists before checking its value.  I am trying to help you when I say avoid `dynamic` at all cost.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take the advice.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you should most likely be using a strongly typed `Persona` class. It will make your code much easier to read, use, and maintain.

However, if you have to use `dynamic`, one thing you could do is replace the item whose property you want to change with a new item that contains the information you want.

Note that, because the list is `dynamic`, we don't know the type of objects it contains, which means that blindly accessing properties of the objects could easily throw an exception.

In order to handle that, you would need to ensure that the property exists before accessing it. AND, we also need to make sure it is the proper type before doing the comparison. This results in pretty ugly code, which is just one more reason to use strongly-typed classes where possible.

```
foreach (var item in ListaPersonas.ToList())
{
    if (item.GetType().GetProperty("Nombre") != null &&
        item.GetType().GetProperty("Nombre").PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)) && 
        item.Nombre == "jose")
    {
        ListaPersonas.Remove(item);
        ListaPersonas.Add(new { valor = 7, Nombre = item.Nombre });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Consider the following:

```
List<dynamic> ListaPersonas = new List<dynamic>() {        
    new { valor = 1, Name = "maria" }, //Has Name, no Nombre
    new { Bar = 2, Nombre="jose" }, //Has Bar, no valor
    new { valor = 3, Foo="juan", Bar = 1 } //has valor, no Nombre, and added Foo & Bar
};
```

This will compile just fine.  Now apply the same logic you did earlier:

```
foreach (var item in ListaPersonas)
{
    //This would throw an exception on dynamics that did not have a "Nombre" property
    if (item.Nombre == "jose") 
    {
        item.valor = 7;
    }            
}
```

This would throw an Exception because not all of the dynamic objects have a property `Nombre`.

### Suggestion

What I would strongly suggest you do is create a class that describes your data:

```
public class Persona
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Valor { get; set; }   
}
```

Then you can easily do the following:

```
List<Persona> ListaPersonas = new List<Persona>() {
    new Persona() { Valor = 1, Nombre="maria" },
    new Persona() { Valor = 2, Nombre="jose" },
    new Persona() { Valor = 3, Nombre="juan" }
}; 

foreach (var item in ListaPersonas)
    if (item.Nombre == "jose")
        item.Valor = 7;
```

Comment: Yep. People should read: [When should I vote down?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) for guidelines on down-votes, and, at the bottom, [What are the alternatives to down-voting?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Most of the time, constructive comments are the way to go, not down-voting.

Comment: Guys, I didn't downvoted your solutions but I think this is not what OP is asking for. I guess he knows how to create a class. It makes more sense what SouXin suggested. The disadvantage it's ExpandoObject can't set properties in the constructor.

Comment: It's just an example, because I really have to create 41 classes in an application, But they are simple class with only public properties, no methods or events. I can not create many class files. The dynamics of objects that allows the transport of data, which do very well. But they can only be read ?. How can I change its values ​​at runtime using dynamic objects?

Comment: The use of `dynamic` in general is pretty dangerous and poor practice.  From what I am understanding of your use-case, you **should not use** `dynamic`.

Comment: @derloopkat Sure, that makes sense. You should add it as an answer. But that reasoning is not a valid reason for downvoting: *"Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *ListaPersonas* getting a list of anonymous objects which are read only.

> ListaPersonas[0].GetType().Name

The above code returns AnonymousType. So we're gonna cast the list as a dynamic `List<ExpandoObject>` by creating an extension class.

Change your code to:

```
    dynamic ListaPersonas = (new List<dynamic>() {
        new { valor= 1,Nombre="maria"},
        new { valor= 2,Nombre="jose"},
        new { valor =3,Nombre="juan"}
    }).ToDynamic();

    foreach (var item in ListaPersonas)
        if (item.Nombre == "jose")
            item.valor = 7;
```

Add this class to your project

```
public static class DynamicExtensions
{
    public static dynamic ToDynamic(this object value)
    {

        var list = new List<ExpandoObject>();
        foreach (var item in (List<dynamic>)value)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item.GetType()))
            {
                expando.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(item));
            }
            list.Add(expando as ExpandoObject);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```